# ANTLR - How to determine what kind of parse tree "best fits" some code

Tags: java, parsing, compiler-construction, antlr, antlr4

I'm building a program with ANTLR where I ask the user to enter some Java code, and it spits out equivalent C# code. In my program, I ask the user to enter some Java code and then parse it. Up until now I've been assuming that they will enter something that will parse as a valid compilation unit on its own, e.g. something like

```
package foo;

class A { ... }
class B { ... }
class C { ... }
```

However, that isn't always the case. They might just enter code from the inside of a class:

```
public void method1() {
    ...
}

public void method2() {
    ...
}
```

Or the inside of a method:

```
System.out.print("hello ");
System.out.println("world!");
```

Or even just an expression:

```
context.getSystemService(Context.ACTIVITY_SERVICE)
```

If I try to parse such snippets by calling `parser.compilationUnit()`, it won't work correctly because most of the code is parsed as error nodes. I need to call the correct method depending on the nature of the code, such as `parser.expression()` or `parser.blockStatements()`. However, I don't want to ask the user to explicitly indicate this. What's the best way to infer what kind of code I'm parsing?

Comment: Create a new top-level parser rule in your grammar that takes all possible input as alternatives, then rely on that. You already have all the rules that need to be put into this new rule in your grammar. For Java, there should be few conflicts - except for fields and local variables, methods and constructors, inner and enclosing types, I don't think you'd have a problem. You did not specify the exact "resolution" of possible input, however.

Comment: @predi I'm not sure what you mean by that last sentence. I like your approach but there's a problem with it: what if the user makes a syntax error, like forgetting a semicolon in a single statement inside many lines of code? Then ANTLR won't match any of the alternatives (even though some are clearly a better fit than others).

Comment: Make sure that your new rule specifies the `EOF` token as the last expected token - if none of the alternatives are matched (not even partially) that could be the reason. By "resolution" I meant how far the user is allowed to drill down, for example, if `<T, V>` is input, would you expect it to be recognized? What about just `Foo`? Those are both valid Java snippets. It would not be a strange requirement for a code generator to expect syntactically correct input only (even if it is just a snippet).

Comment: @predi Huh, you're saying that ANTLR will match an alternative even if there are a nonzero number of syntax errors? I haven't tried it empirically, I just assumed that even a single error would make it rule out an alternative completely. If it manages to somehow not do that, that's impressive.

Comment: I don't like the idea with the new top-level parse rule because of it pollutes a grammar.

Answer (score 1):

Rather than trying to guess a valid grammar rule entry point to parse a language snippet of unknown scope, progressively add scope wrappers to the source text until a valid top-level rule parse is achieved.

That is, with each successive parse failure, progressively add dummy package, class, & method statements as source text wrappers.

Whichever wrapper was added to achieve a successful parse will then be a known quantity. Therefore, the parse tree node representing the original source text can be easily identified.

Probably want to use a fail-fast parser; construct the parser with the `BailErrorStrategy` to obtain this behavior.

Answer (score 1):

Our algorithm in [Swiftify](https://objectivec2swift.com/#/converter/) tries to select the best suitable parse rule from the defined rule set. This web-service converts Objective-C code fragments to Swift and you can estimate the quality of conversion immediately by your own.

### Algorithm

We use open-sourced [ObjectiveC grammar](https://github.com/antlr/grammars-v4/blob/master/objc). Detail Steps of algorithm look like this:

1. Parse input Objective-C code fragment with the following rules

   - `translationUnit`
   - `implementationDefinitionList`
   - `interfaceDeclarationList`
   - `expression`
   - `compoundStatement`
2. If parse result of the certain rule does not contain any error returns this 
   rule at once.
3. Select the rule with the nearest to the end parse error.
4. If there are two or more rules with the same nearest to the end error 
   location, select the rule with the minimum number of syntax errors.

## Demo

There are test code samples that parsed with different parse rules:

- `translationUnit`: http://swiftify.me/clye5z
- `implementationDefinitionList`: http://swiftify.me/fpasza
- `interfaceDeclarationList`: http://swiftify.me/13rv2j
- `compoundStatement`: http://swiftify.me/4cpl9n

Our algorithm is able to detect suitably parse rule even with an incorrect input:

- `compoundStatement` with errors: http://swiftify.me/13rv2j/1